# Error when parsing string with regex: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex

I've been getting the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. From my understanding that's when my regex is not returning any results. I've tried it on an online regex tester and it worked though. Can someone tell me what's going on? I'm looking to have

ExecutionDateTime: 04/01/2015 10:51:08.580

ExecutionSpeed: 2.0000 ms

DatabaseType: SQLite

DatabaseFileName: Local.db3

QueryName: ViewPersonEmail

```
import re

s = "04/01/2015 10:51:08.580 | OUTLOOK |  6 | INFO  |     2.0000 ms: | SQLite | Local.db3 | Executing select query for entity type ViewPersonEmail"

def extract_data(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r"""(?P<date>.*?)\s\|.+\INFO\s*\|\s*
                             (?P<speed>.*?)\:\s\|\s+
                             (?P<type>.*?)\s\|\s*
                             (?P<file>.*?)\s.*\Executing\s\S+\s\query for entity type\s
                             (?P<query>.*)""", re.VERBOSE)
    match = pattern.match(s)

    ExecutionDateTime = match.group("date")
    ExecutionSpeed = match.group("speed")
    DatabaseType = match.group("type")
    DatabaseFileName = match.group("file")
    QueryName = match.group("query")

    return (ExecutionDateTime, ExecutionSpeed, DatabaseType, DatabaseFileName, QueryName)

print extract_data(s)
```

A separate question I have is what's the best way of parsing through an entire file to find strings similar to the one above to that to output into another file? I imagined I can do the same as above but have

```
log = open(text.log)
def extract_data(log)...
```

though I'm not sure if that's correct

Comment: you cant split the text by "|" and trim the parts to remove spaces

Comment: @Zital Ok, I just tried it in one line without using re.verbose and it worked. I wanted to make it look tidier, what's the best way to approach that?

Comment: In your regex you have `query for entity type` - you need to escape the spaces, if you use it with `re.VERBOSE`.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `sub` method instead of groups?

Comment: @Morb No I haven't, I'll look into it

Comment: To use `sub`, you'll need to change the pattern.

This one works: `^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).+?\|\s+INFO\s+\|\s+(\S.*? ms):\s+\|\s+(.+?)\s+\|\s+(.+?)\s+\|\s+(.+?)$`

Answer (score 0):

This is a much straightforward solution without `re`

```
s = "04/01/2015 10:51:08.580 | OUTLOOK |  6 | INFO  |     2.0000 ms: | SQLite | Local.db3 | Executing select query for entity type ViewPersonEmail"

ExecutionDateTime, _, _ , _, ExecutionSpeed, DatabaseType, DatabaseFileName, TempQueryName = map(str.strip, s.split("|"))
QueryName = TempQueryName.split()[-1]
```

Comment: I appreciate the alternative solution but I'm personally trying to learn re. In addition to this, ExecutionSpeed in your case would have "2.0000 ms:" wouldn't it? I'm looking for "2.0000 ms" without the colon

Comment: `ExecutionSpeed = ExecutionSpeed[:-1]` will give you that.